# How to parse multiple pandas Datetime formats

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe that unfortunately switches datetime formats from:

[image: first part of pandas dataframe with one DT format]

to:

[image: second part of pandas dataframe with another DT format]

I need to parse the df['DT'] into a Datetime and then a DatetimeIndex.  It seems to work, but then keeps the two types of datetimes:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'])
df = df.set_index('Datetime')
del df['DT']
```

[image: dataframe]
[image: datafarme]

But the pandas timeseries functionality does not work, i.e.:

```
from datetime import time
df.between_time(time(0),time(8,59,59))
```

Throws the error: TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex.

I would therefor like to know how to parse these two different Datetime formats into a single DateTimeIndex.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

first of all, try the following:

```
In[54]: b = '2010-10-02T24:00:00+0000'

In[55]: pd.to_datetime(b,errors='raise')
(... ...)
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

This tells u that the datetime format of variable {b} is wrong.  so two choices here. the first one is to correct the str format (modify "24" to "00"), then apply the {pd.to_datetime} func:

```
In[56]: df
Out[56]: 
                              0
0  11/23/2014 01:37:00 AM +0000
1      2010-10-02T00:00:00+0000

In[57]: pd.to_datetime(df[0])
Out[57]: 
0   2014-11-23 01:37:00
1   2010-10-02 00:00:00
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

the second one would be to specify the format within {pd.to_datetime} func so that it can recognize ur special str format (which is not very straightforward if u want to keep ur time info in this case)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I actually hadn't noticed that the second datetime format was so ill-formed.  Given that I have ~370,000 rows of good data, I think it makes most sense to simply delete the ill-formed rows as they constitute less than 1% of the data.  The issue then disappears!